# How do I find my error in XCode? (iphone project)

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

I'm still relatively new to XCode.  I'm trying to build an iPhone application and after my `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method runs but not inside of any code I can find I get this error:
`[58036:207] *** -[_PFArray release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x17cd2fe0`
I have no idea what that means apart from the fact that some array somewhere is being released when it's already released?
The real problem, is that I have no clue how to use the information provided there to find where the error is.  There is no line of code to look in, no variable name, etc.
How do I use this information to find what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try enabling zombies, then xcode puts a breakpoint automatically to the line where this error occurs. Google nszombieenabled for more information

Edit: Well, I don't have much thing to do so here your guide,

1. Open instruments. It is an application and you can find it in "~/Developer/applications/instruments" (in a default installation path). Instruments will be your right hand so master it well.
2. In the opening screen, you will see a bunch of templates. Open the one named "Zombies". Note: You will often use the template named "Leaks". It shows all the memory leaks you forget to release.
3. From "choose target" (top left corner), select "choose target", and again select "choose target". From here, browse the project directory, and choose "build/Debug-iphonesimulator/executableName". Here I assume that you have built your project in debug profile with nszombieenabled to true. If not, build it so and reply 3.
4. Press record button (top left corner). The simulator will appear and your app will start. Then reproduce the error you have encountered.
5. Instruments will interrupt the app showing a message bubble. Do not close the bubble. From the bar in the middle of the window, select "objects list" instead of "statistics". Now, all the objects allocated up to this point lies in a list sorted by their memory addresses. Here scroll down to the memory address written inside the bubble. You can type the initial letters for fast scroll. Then double click the line you found. This brings you to the code where the object is allocated IF THE CODE IS YOURS. If it is not, then ios allocated the object. But do not worry, and double click the lines below and above to see if they are allocated by you. This should give you a hint where may be the problem is since these lines triggered ios to allocate the object (possibly).

This is all I can say. I hope you can find what causes this error.

Comment: NSZombie is already enabled and no such breakpoint occurs.  I just get a "GDB Interrupted" message and when I look at the console that error is what I see.

Comment: Then ios system does the last release. I can only advice you to search the address 0x17cd2fe0 from the instruments. In instruments there is a zombies template which can help you. When the program is interrupted, search for the given address from the all allocations. This is a bit tiring but i don't know any other solution, sorry.

Comment: By the way, you can also look for the near addresses to the given one to give you a clue.

Comment: I appreciate the help...but I am a complete XCode newb pretty much and what you are saying appears to be gibberish to me.  I will try to figure it out, but if it's possible for someone to easily give a step by step instruction on how to search for those addresses it would greatly help me out!

Comment: THANK YOU!  Still hasn't solved my problem but thank you for the effort!  That line (and all the lines around it) are occuring the CoreData Library...specifically the `prepareResultsFromResultSet:usingFetchingPlan:withMatchingRows` method.